# _ASM_EXTABLE_HANDLE virtualization compilation failure

Tags: c, linux, makefile, hypervisor

I'm trying to compile [this project from github](https://github.com/shubham0d/ProtoVirt) but I am running into the following error:

```
make -C /lib/modules/5.15.0-53-generic/build M=/home/jr/Documents/ProtoVirt modules EXTRA_CFLAGS="-g -DDEBUG"
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-53-generic'
warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
  The kernel was built by: gcc (Ubuntu 11.2.0-19ubuntu1) 11.2.0
  You are using:           gcc (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.3.0
  CC [M]  /home/jr/Documents/ProtoVirt/protovirt.o
In file included from /home/jr/Documents/ProtoVirt/protovirt.c:23:
/home/jr/Documents/ProtoVirt/protovirt.h: In function ‘__rdmsr1’:
/home/jr/Documents/ProtoVirt/protovirt.h:25:22: error: expected ‘:’ or ‘)’ before ‘_ASM_EXTABLE_HANDLE’
   25 |                      _ASM_EXTABLE_HANDLE(1b, 2b, ex_handler_rdmsr_unsafe)
      |                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/jr/Documents/ProtoVirt/protovirt.h:25:42: error: invalid suffix "b" on integer constant
   25 |                      _ASM_EXTABLE_HANDLE(1b, 2b, ex_handler_rdmsr_unsafe)
      |                                          ^~
/home/jr/Documents/ProtoVirt/protovirt.h:25:46: error: invalid suffix "b" on integer constant
   25 |                      _ASM_EXTABLE_HANDLE(1b, 2b, ex_handler_rdmsr_unsafe)
      |                                              ^~
/home/jr/Documents/ProtoVirt/protovirt.c: In function ‘initVmcsControlField’:
/home/jr/Documents/ProtoVirt/protovirt.c:282:9: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Wdeclaration-after-statement]
  282 |         void *costum_rip;
      |         ^~~~
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:297: /home/jr/Documents/ProtoVirt/protovirt.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1903: /home/jr/Documents/ProtoVirt] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-53-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:12: modules] Error 2
```

The command I'm running is make. Can anyone explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The compiler doesn't recognise `_ASM_EXTABLE_HANDLE` as a macro because the project doesn't have proper header includes.

Comment: @Siguza thanks for your response. How should I modify the header includes to recognize the macro?

Comment: Well there's various things that should be defined, like kzalloc, DECLARE_ARGS, _ASM_EXTABLE_HANDLE, etc. Find out which headers these come from, then include them. They should all be part of the kernel headers, I suppose.

Comment: @Siguza Thank you for your response. I'm very new to this. How can I look up the headers that these come from? I tried googling but I didn't really find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `_ASM_EXTABLE_HANDLE` macro is replaced by `_ASM_EXTABLE_TYPE` in the newest kernel versions.